# Seeking halachic arguments for starting the Passover Seders earlier than Tzeit

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada

Another thread (Starting the Seder after Sheki'ah (sunset)? [Starting the Seder after Sheki'ah (sunset)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27232/starting-the-seder-after-shekiah-sunset/128942?noredirect=1#comment427332_128942)) included a discussion of the starting time of the Seders.  This led me to search for halachic arguments that support starting the Seder(s) at some point in time before tzeit.

Comment: In response to the question link above,  I posted an answer with some plausible halachic arguments I found on the web that support starting the Seder(s) before tzeit.  But my answer was hidden, for reasons not clear to me. So I am posting this question to encourage exploration of the topic of starting the Passover Seders earlier than tzeit.

Comment: similar question of yours https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/102023/759

Comment: @YehudaW you might consider posting your answer from that other question here.

Comment: I don't believe we distinguish any point between shkiya and 3 stars halachically

Comment: @יהושע that's mostly true, but there are multiple opinions of when each of those is, so there are effectively lots of possibilities

Comment: @יהושעק Just more technically speaking, it's a three way machloket in the Talmud when between sunset and nightfall the period of doubt begins, so while generally we are strict all the way from sunset, we might only be lenient about some rules later than sunset when the official period of doubt has certainly begun.